# Which senses does ob have in the following words?

Tags: meaning, morphology, preposition

Oxford Latin Dictionary says that prep. ob has the following senses:

> ob prep.
>
> 1. In the direction of, towards.
> 2. In front of or in the way of (so as to block).
> 3. - a. (giving the  grounds  for  an  attitude,  etc.)  By reason of, on the score of, because of.
>    - b. (giving the emotion which prompts an action) under the impulsion of, as a result of, because of.
>    - c. as a result of (an occasioning circumstance), on account of, because of.
>    - d. as a reward or punishment for, in return for, on account of.
>    - e. quam ob rem: see quamobrem.
> 4. With a  view  to,  in  connection  with;  ob  suam partem, on one's own account,
>
>    - b. ob rem, to some purpose, usefully.
> 5. On behalf of, in the interests of.
> 6. In payment for, so as to pay for;  (spec., w. ref. to bribes)  as payment for (services rendered),
>
>    - b. in payment of (a debt or tax).
> 7. On the occasion of, as a commemoration of.

Which senses does ob have in the following words:

- occido
- omitto
- occipio
- offero
- obtineo

?

Answer (score 8):

You are mistaking stand-alone preposition **ob** (which would be used before nouns) with prefix **ob-** (which was used to derive new words, primarily verbs).

Latin, Greek, [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_verbs#German_prefixes), Slavic languages widely use (prepositional) prefixes to derive new verbs. Exact meaning of derived verb is often not predictable from theoretical meaning of prefix and meaning of base verb.

This feature of grammar exists in lesser degree in modern English. Who could predict meaning of *understand* (*under-* + *stand*)?

Latin preposition *ob* comes from Proto-Italic preposition [**op*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Italic/op) which has reconstructed meaning "towards". I think that especially during derivation of verbs, this meaning would have been originally assumed. Even if such meaning was originally used, meanings of words can change over time, and new meanings can develop. (The other meanings of Latin preposition *ob* are described separately for English-speaking learners of Latin, but I think that it is not certain that ancient Romans thought of them as distinct meanings.)

Comment: ob- was derived from ob, so has meanings inherited

Comment: @Tim Original meaning of this preposition is [reconstructed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Italic/op) to be the first one of meanings which you listed, i.e. "in the direction of, towards". It is quite likely that this meaning was used for derivation of all these verbs, but meanings of verbs could have changed over time, and new meanings could have developed.

Comment: Isn't your comment above more relevant as an answer than the body of your answer? I don't think the premise of this question is utterly misguided, despite the reception. The meaning of "de-" as a verb prefix can't be fully derived from the meaning of "de" the preposition, but they're not unrelated!

Comment: +1 That last point is most salient and one of the biggest misunderstandings of language learners. In the phrase, "I'm watching you, " does *watch* mean "to spy on", "to view", "to spot check", or "to protect"? The answer is "yes." And no English speaker will divide it up so nicely. So it's a mistake to think that one "definition" of that prefix is what those words are utilizing.